# Spring MVC custom converter not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a custom Converter for my Spring MVC application but it is never triggered.

Here's how I implemented it and registered it :

```
public class ObjectIdSpringConverter implements Converter<String, ObjectId>{

    public ObjectIdSpringConverter(){
        System.out.println("ObjectIdSpringConverter picked up ");
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectId convert(String source) {
        System.out.println("ObjectIdSpringConverter converting");
        return new ObjectId(source);        
    }
}
```

And in my Spring MVC configuration I register it as follow :

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"myapp.web.controller"}) 
 public class SpringMvcConf  extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

   @Override
   protected void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
       registry.addConverter(new ObjectIdSpringConverter());
   }
   //other stuff here
}
```

I placed some breakpoints in the converter's constructor and convert() method, and I can see that it is properly constructed, however the convert() method is never called which results in icorrect values received by my controller.

Here's an example controller method :

```
  @Controller
  public class HomeController {

         @RequestMapping(value="/home/testObjectId.amlgm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public ObjectId testObjectId(ObjectId oid){
            System.out.println("expected 552952cec9ac88712ee0d36b, actual " + oid.toString());
            System.out.println(oid);
            return oid;
         }

   }
```

I know the convert method is never called because the break point is never hit and because the value is not the expected one. I also debugged / traced what spring was doing and it does not seem to use my converter to instantiate the parameter ObjectId of the controller method.

Can anyone point me to what I am missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your formatter should implement `Formatter<T>`,  where T will be ObjectId in your case

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/FormatterRegistry.html#addFormatter-org.springframework.format.Formatter-

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason this doesn't work either... I get the exact same results. I am gonna try on a fresh project and let you know my results.